# Problems with asp HttpResponse on a download from Android

Tags: android, httpresponse

I have the following problem:

1. I develop a .zip file download with .pdf selected inside a function on c#.
2. The function creates the .zip file on a temp folder on the server and the HTTP Response return this file.
   This function works great when is called from windows, and IOS. But when I call this function on Android it never downloads the file.

On the server I see that the function create the .zip file again and again when it's called from android browser (chrome, dolphin...) and it's never returned.

The strange thing is that I could run it well when I selected 90 .pdf files (although the function is called twice for no reason), but when I select 140 (or more) the issue happens again.

Here is the code:

```
            **string dirName = Utiles.GetNewName();        
            zipName += ".ZIP\"";
            string urlRet = _mSTempPath + @"\" + dirName + ".ZIP";
            string urlDelete = _mSTempPath + @"\" + dirName;
            System.IO.Stream iStream = null;
            // Total bytes to read:
            long dataToRead;          
            //HttpResponse resp = _page.Response;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                foreach (string url in filesURLs)
                {
                    zip.AddFile(url,"");
                }
                zip.Save(_mSTempPath + @"\" + dirName + ".ZIP");
            }
            // Open the file.
            iStream = new System.IO.FileStream(urlRet, System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                        System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read);
            // Total bytes to read:
            dataToRead = iStream.Length;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",                  "attachment;filename=\"" + zipName);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length",   dataToRead.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;

            HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(urlRet);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();**
```

Please, I will be very grateful if anyone can help.
Thanks again!